# Selecting rows with more than one occurence of column value from joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query which returns a joined table, it looks like the following:

```
| id_cart | id_customer | date_add              |
| ------- | ----------- | --------------------- |
| 1       | 100         | 2017-07-24 | 10:48:00 |
| ------- | ----------- | --------------------- |
| 2       | 101         | 2016-02-14 | 15:43:05 |
| ------- | ----------- | --------------------- |
| 3       | 100         | 2015-04-12 | 01:59:34 |
```

I'd like to make it so that from these results, only rows with more than one occurrence in the `id_customer` column are selected - I'm assuming it'd look something like this:

```
| id_cart | id_customer | date_add              | customer_count |
| ------- | ----------- | --------------------- | -------------- |
| 1       | 100         | 2017-07-24 | 10:48:00 | 2              |
| ------- | ----------- | --------------------- | -------------- |
| 3       | 100         | 2015-04-12 | 01:59:34 | 2              |
```

The issue I'm facing is most questions I've seen from others are looking for the count of multiple value occurrences, whereas I'm only interested in seeing the results - not the count. Also by using a joined table I'm unsure on how to refer back to it as a variable/alias, instead of just copy & pasting a horribly long query over and over again.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry The only real thing I'm having an issue with is referring back to the joined table, as I can't figure out how to give it a variable/alias. I'm not asking for an MCVE - I'm fine to be pointed in the right direction to figure it out for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL I would do this:

```
select *
from (select stuff from bigjoin) a1
inner join
(
select id_customer
from (select stuff from bigjoin)
group by id_customer
having count(*) > 1
) x1
on x1.id_Customer = a1.id_customer
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue I'm having is that 'MyTable' is the result of a joined table - and I'm not sure how to refer to that. I've tried altering yours, but it's not valid:

`SELECT * FROM (big join query here) a1 INNER JOIN (SELECT id_customer FROM a1 GROUP BY id_customer GROUP BY id_customer HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) x1 ON x1.id_customer = a1.id_customer`

Comment: My bad, just realised I added two GROUP BY's - the error is now that it can't find the table a1, as MySQL thinks it's an actual table in the database - not a result set.

Comment: @RobT. That's not going to work, see the edit. You cannot reference a1 like that, you need to do the join again...

Comment: Gotcha - that's worked, thanks! Is there no way to avoid repeating myself with the long query? I would've thought there was a way to reference it, since it's the exact same thing twice over.

Comment: @RobT. In every other DBMS, yes. But MySQL lacks CTEs (aka `with` clause)